# JavaScript: Alert.Show(message) From ASP.NET Code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am reading this [JavaScript: Alert.Show(message) From ASP.NET Code-behind](http://archive.devnewz.com/devnewz-3-20061129JavaScriptAlertShowmessagefromASPNETCodebehind.html)

I am trying to implement the same. So I created a static class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Registration.DataAccess
{
    public static class Repository
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Shows a client-side JavaScript alert in the browser. 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="message">The message to appear in the alert.</param> 
        public static void Show(string message) 
            { 
               // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks 
               string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\'"); 
               string script = "<script type="text/javascript">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>"; 

               // Gets the executing web page 
               Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page; 

               // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page 
               if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert")) 
               { 
                 page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Alert), "alert", script); 
               } 
            } 
    }
}
```

On this line:

```
string script = "<script type="text/javascript">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";
```

It is showing me the error: **; Expected**

And also on

```
page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Alert), "alert", script);
```

Err: **The type or namespace name 'Alert' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Here is an easy way:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");
```

Comment: I don't like this way. You'll never know where your code will be inserted, because it's inserted into stream. Also it potentially could break HTML and cause Javascript errors. RegisterClientScriptBlock is right way to run Javascript on client.

Answer (score 24):

```
string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');", cleanMessage);
if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert")) 
{
    page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "alert", script, true /* addScriptTags */);
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This message show the alert message directly

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"showalert","alert('Only alert Message');",true);
```

This message show alert message from JavaScript function

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "displayalertmessage", "Showalert();", true);
```

These are two ways to display alert messages in c# code behind

Answer (score 10):

if you are using ScriptManager on the page then you can also try using this:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertBox", "alert('Your Message');", true);
```

Comment: This works, but only if the page is static and not redirected (see my answer elsewhere). If you have a Response.Redirect() after this to reload the page for example, the message does not display. There needs to be a forced wait until user presses OK or something.

Comment: Yes, we use code v. similar to the above, mostly it works for us, but in some code it just doesn't work, possibly for the reason described by @Fandango68, above.

Answer (score 5):

Try this method:

```
public static void Show(string message) 
{                
    string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\'");                               
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page; 
    string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');", cleanMessage);
    if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert")) 
    {
        page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "alert", script, true /* addScriptTags */);
    } 
}
```

In Vb.Net

```
Public Sub Show(message As String)
    Dim cleanMessage As String = message.Replace("'", "\'")
    Dim page As Page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler
    Dim script As String = String.Format("alert('{0}');", cleanMessage)
    If (page IsNot Nothing And Not page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert")) Then
        page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "alert", script, True) ' /* addScriptTags */
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not compile. The string you have terminates unexpectedly;

```
string script = "<script type=";
```

That's effectively what you've written. You need to escape your double quotes:

```
string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";
```

This kind of thing should be painfully obvious since your source code coloring should be completely jacked.

Comment: Come on @Tejs, give a break :) Third question in a row that you arrive a few seconds earlier :)

Comment: Thanks! What about the Alert err?

Comment: It's probably a side effect of the jacked code. Impossible to say without fixing the earlier bug.

Comment: Thanks Tejs. But I am not getting any alert mesg from the above code.

Comment: What does the browser (firebug, developer tools, dragonfly, ...) say? Any error messages on the script tabs?

Comment: Can you physically write an alert statement on your page (not through C#) and see if it pops the alert box? You should be able to see the script block in the final output.

Answer (score 4):

There could be more than one reasons for not working.

1: Are you calling your function properly? i.e.

```
Repository.Show("Your alert message");
```

2: Try using RegisterStartUpScript method instead of scriptblock.

3: If you are using UpdatePanel, that could be an issue as well.

Check [this(topic 3.2)](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/JavaScript_with_ASP_NET_2_0_Pages_Part1.aspx#s8)

Answer (score 4):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('ID Exists ')</script>");
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping a code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.

Answer (score 3):

And i think, the line:

```
string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\'");
```

does not work, it must be:

```
string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\\'");
```

You need to mask the `\` with a `\` and the `'` with another `\`.

Answer (score 3):

**Calling a JavaScript function from code behind**

Step 1 Add your Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Func() {
        alert("hello!")
    }
</script>
```

Step 2 Add 1 **Script Manager** in your webForm and Add 1 **button** too

Step 3 Add this code in your button click event

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Func()", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you want to display the alert box to appear on the same page, without displaying on a blank page.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Sorry there are no attachments');", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

The quotes around type="text/javascript" are ending your string before you want to. Use single quotes inside to avoid this problem.

Use this

```
 type='text/javascript'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix this line:

```
string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";
```

And also this one:

```
RegisterClientScriptBlock("alert", script); //lose the typeof thing
```

Comment: Thanks! What about the Alert err?

Comment: Thanks Andrian. But I am not getting any alert mesg from the above code.

Comment: You should fix one thing at a time. Does this error still happens after you fix the string?

Comment: Nops! The err is gone. Build is a success but it is not showing me any kind of alert mesg..

Answer (score 2):

```
string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');", cleanMessage);     
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "key_name", script );", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Works 100% without any problem and will not redirect to another page...I tried just copying this and changing your message

```
// Initialize a string and write Your message it will work
string message = "Helloq World";
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("alert('");
sb.Append(message);
sb.Append("');");
ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method after sending the client-side code as a string parameter.

**NOTE**: I didn't come up with this solution, but I came across it when I was searching for a way to do so myself, I only edited it a little.

It is very simple and helpful, and can use it to perform more than 1 line of javascript/jquery/...etc or any client-side code

```
private void MessageBox(string msg)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" + msg + "')</script>";
    Page.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9365713/824068

Comment: I think there were some pieces missing. "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + msg + "');</script>"

Answer (score 1):

```
string script = "<script type="text/javascript">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";
```

You should use string.Format in this case. This is better coding style. For you it would be:

```
string script = string.Format(@"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}');</script>");
```

Also note that when you should escape " symbol or use apostroph instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void MessageBox(string msg)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text  = string.Format(@"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}');</script>",msg);
    Page.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [escape your quotes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) (Take a look at the "Special characters" section). You can do it by adding a slash before them:

```
string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";
  Response.Write(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this and it works, as long as the page is not redirect afterwards. Would be nice to have it show, and wait until the user clicks OK, regardless of redirects.

```
/// <summary>
/// A JavaScript alert class
/// </summary>
public static class webMessageBox
{

/// <summary>
/// Shows a client-side JavaScript alert in the browser.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The message to appear in the alert.</param>
    public static void Show(string message)
    {
       // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks
       string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");
       string wsScript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";

       // Gets the executing web page
       Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

       // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't allready on the Page
       if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
       {
           //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MessageBox", wsScript, true);
           page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(webMessageBox), "alert", wsScript, false);
       }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling script only can not do that if the event is PAGE LOAD event specially.

you need to call,
Response.Write(script);

so as above,
string script = "alert('" + cleanMessage + "');";
  Response.Write(script);

will work in at least for a page load event for sure.

Comment: Sample code 1:string close = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                                window.returnValue = true;
                                window.close();
                                </script>";
                    base.Response.Write(close);

Comment: sample code 2:string close = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                                alert('This is my alert');
                                </script>";
                    base.Response.Write(close);

Answer (score 1):

if u Want To massage on your code behind file then try this

```
string popupScript = "<script language=JavaScript>";
popupScript += "alert('Your Massage');";

popupScript += "</";
popupScript += "script>";
Page.RegisterStartupScript("PopupScript", popupScript);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code.

```
 StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
 strScript.Append("alert('your Message goes here');");
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Script", strScript.ToString(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!--Java Script to hide alert message after few second -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HideLabel() {
            var seconds = 5;
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("<%=divStatusMsg.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
            }, seconds * 1000);
        };
    </script>
    <!--Java Script to hide alert message after few second -->
```

Answer (score -3):

its simple to call a message box, so if you want to code behind or call function, I think it is better or may be not. There is a process, you can just use namespace

```
using system.widows.forms;
```

then, where you want to show a message box, just call it as simple, as in C#, like:

```
messagebox.show("Welcome");
```

Comment: The question is about showing a message on the client - with Javascript

Comment: If only in were so :^/