# Javascript/C# - Confirmation Dialog if statement conditions are met

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm working in C# to replace a file in a Sharepoint library, I've got a method which checks for the existence of the file but based on the result of this I need there to be a confirmation dialog box for the user to warn them that they are about to overwrite a file which already exists.

Please see my snippet below:

```
using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
       {
           var pageUrl = webUrl + "Pages/home.aspx";
           var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");

           if (fileExists(list, pageUrl))
           {
               // show confirmation dialog here
           }
       }
```

Then I'd like to have some logic based on the result of my confirmation dialog which will either continue executing the code or just `return;`

I've been looking at the [ClientScriptManager class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) and although it is close I can't seem to get it to do exactly what I want (a logic dependent confirmation dialog).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this post?
[JavaScript: Alert.Show(message) From ASP.NET Code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825165/javascript-alert-showmessage-from-asp-net-code-behind)

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");
```

Or

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"showalert","alert('Only alert Message');",true)
```

Comment: I use this approach a lot; it works really well when you use a StringBuilder for any complex script (which is basically anything beyond the one-line example). Depending on the version of the framework you're working with the code to register the script may vary a bit (in Visual Studio you'll see the underline if it's deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer below but to get a confirmation use conform instead of alert as follows:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(), "confirmation", "confirm('Are you sure you want to overwrite?');", true);
```