# C#: Namespace ' Forms ' does not exist in the namespace ' System.Windows '

Tags: c#, forms, namespaces

I have a web application and I wanted to show a message to the user, so I searched the web and I found System.Windows.Forms, but when I tried to use it I am getting the following error:

CS0234 : The type or namespace name ' Forms ' does not exist in the namespace ' System.Windows ' (are you missing an assembly reference ? )

I just added the "using System.Windows.Forms" sentence and also right-clicked the solution, went to "Add reference" and checked "System.Windows.Forms" item.
For Visual Studio there is no error, so I compile the solution but when I try to open that form I get the error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AcademiaSparta;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AcademiaSpartaWeb
{
    public partial class Registrarse : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hola");
        }
    }
}
```

I am searching since 3 hours and I cannot find an answer.

PS: Sorry if my question has gramatical mistakes, I am not very good in english.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to show message box in a client's browser?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying.

Comment: Well, `System.Windows.Forms` is a totally wrong way to go then...

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825165/javascript-alert-showmessage-from-asp-net-code-behind

Comment: You want to use an Alert. Unfortunately it's not as nice as with windows forms.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms` is for desktop applications, it wouldn't do you any good when creating web application. If you want to show a message box on the browser you need to use Javascript's Alert.

Comment: I did not realize System.Windows.Forms is fot desktop apps. Thanks a lot to everyone. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Or create a method like this in your solution:

```
public static class MessageBox {
    public static void Show(this Page Page, String Message) {
       Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
          Page.GetType(),
          "MessageBox",
          "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + Message + "');</script>"
       );
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hola");
```

Comment: Thanks Vikram Bose for your answer. I understood the mistake with the System.Windows.Forms.