# Show message half way through processing method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a number program. Part of it looping through numbers and half way through I want it to stop and ask the user if they want to continue.

```
public bool NumberLoop()
{
    int max = 100;
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < max)
    {
        counter++;

        if (counter == 50)
        {
             bool userWantsToContinue = // Show the user a message box asking if they want to continue

             if (!userWantsToContinue)
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample snippet of what I have so far. To note the method above is in a C# class library and this is called from an aspx page in a web application project. Preferably I was looking at having the message box appear in a new browser window with 2 buttons yes and no.

Comment: Is your question on the best practice of pausing the execution or how to show the alert dialogue to the user?

Comment: How to show the alert dialogue to the user.

Comment: Can you talk us through _why_ you want to prompt the user?

Comment: The likely simplest solution is to split the problem into three parts. a) Send AJAX request to go through first half of numbers. b) JS based prompt / question c) Send AJAX request to go through second half of numbers (if they say yes to b)).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest wat to show this alert would be through the JavaScript function `Window.confirm()`.

Here are the docs on how this method is used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

It'll return the boolean `true` if the user hits "ok" and `false` otherwise.

Here's a similar StackOverflow question if you want the entire logic to live in the code behind: [JavaScript: Alert.Show(message) From ASP.NET Code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825165/javascript-alert-showmessage-from-asp-net-code-behind)